# Error in your SQL syntax - line 19

Tags: mysql, syntax, line, mysql-error-1064

I have a MySQL problem. What is not working?

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 19

```
SELECT * , SUBSTRING( CONVERT( attributes
USING latin1 ) 
FROM 18 ) AS 'duplicated serials'
FROM player_items
WHERE SUBSTRING( CONVERT( attributes
USING latin1 ) 
FROM 18 ) 
IN (

SELECT SUBSTRING( CONVERT( attributes
USING latin1 ) 
FROM 18 ) 
FROM player_depotitems
WHERE CONVERT( attributes
USING latin1 ) LIKE '%serial%'
GROUP BY SUBSTRING( CONVERT( attributes
USING latin1 ) 
FROM 18 ) 
HAVING COUNT( * ) >0
```

Thanks for help. I no have more idea.

Comment: Your parentheses aren't balanced. There's no close parenthesis for the parenthesis after `IN`.

Comment: As a rule, if the error message says " near '' " , it's a fairly safe bet that missing parentheses are involved!

Answer (score 2):

The `IN` has no closing parenthesis.

Comment: @sessam5, correct, put a closing parenthesis AFTER the > 0 )